# Проблема с TYPO3 и MYSQL

Tags: php, cms, mysql

Имеется [сайт](http://www.sleepsystem.ru/).
Собран с помощью шаблонизатора TemplaVoilà.
В коде сайта на всех страницах, кроме главной (на ней закоммертировано), имеется запись (примерно на 186 строке):

```
<script src="http://savehalf.traffictools.ru/counter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Из-за нее сайт грузится более 20 секунд. Необходимо данную запись убрать.

Сидит данная строка в базе данных MYSQL. В таблице "tx templavoila tmplobj"  в столбце: "templatemapping" в трех записях, в файлах BLOB.

При редактировании данных файлов через dbForge Studio for МуСКЛ и удалении нужной строки сайт перестает работать с ошибкой:

> Template Object could not be
> unserialized successfully. Are you
> sure you saved mapping information
> into Template Object with UID "4"

Кажется, что проблема в кириллических символах внутри данных BLOB файлах, но удалить их нет никакой возможности. Нужна помощь.